# Vuetify: item-text attribute breaks v-combobox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm only getting started with Vue.js and Vuetify and I'm having a very simple issue concerning the v-combobox component:

Let's say, I would like to display a combobox offering three different options. The following example works just fine ([Codepen A](https://codepen.io/jdoe2442/pen/OJmwGWQ?editors=1011)):

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-combobox
              v-model="selectedItem"
              :items="items"
              item-text="label"
              label="Item"
              filled
          ></v-combobox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
const myVue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: null,
      items: [
        {id: 1, label: "one"},
        {id: 2, label: "two"},
        {id: 3, label: "three"}
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

Now, let's say I want to change the `item-text` attribute to perform just a slightly more complex transformation ([Codepen B](https://codepen.io/jdoe2442/pen/abWjMEM?editors=1011)):

```html
<v-combobox
    :item-text="item => item.label.toUpperCase()"
    ...
></v-combobox>
```

Now, all suggestions are displayed in uppercase letters, but selecting one only works on the first try. It's impossible to select a different option after that.

I really don't see what's wrong here. What am I missing?

Comment: That seems like a bug in Vuetify. You should file a GitHub issue.

Comment: The solution suggested by @Idan works just fine. I have created a GitHub issue though concerning the v-model part:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model` can be limited with change options

Using `:value` should do the work

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-combobox
              :value="selectedItem"
              :items="items"
              :item-text="item => item.label.toUpperCase()"
              label="Item"
              filled
          ></v-combobox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```